# Flextras dropdownlist not working properly

Tags: apache-flex

I have successfully added a dropdownlist(flextras) but its not working properly. Whenever I touch the dropdown, the list that pops up goes under the textboxes(which are placed below the dropdownlist). Therefore I'm not being able to select the item from list on top of the textbox, as the focus passes to the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pleased read this [blog post on the subject](https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/5/1/Why-does-a-TextInput-appear-above-my-Popup-in-Flex-46).

The relevant quote:

> The default skin for a TextInput in Flex 4.6 uses the
>   [StyleableStageText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/StyleableStageText.html).  StageText is always drawn above the Flash
>   Display List, which is why the drop down's popup appears to be under
>   it.  To quote the [Adobe docs on StageText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/StyleableStageText.html):
>
> [start doc quote] Native text input fields cannot be clipped by other Flex content and
>   are rendered in a layer above the Stage. Because of this limitation,
>   components that use StageText-based skin classes will always appear to
>   be on top of other Flex components. Flex popups and drop-downs will
>   also be obscured by any visible native text fields. Finally, native
>   text fields' relative z-order cannot be controlled by the application. [end doc quote]
>
> There are two possible solutions for this.  The first is to architect
>   your mobile application so that popups never display above a
>   TextInput.  This may be tough if you're building for multiple devices
>   with different screen sizes.
>
> The second is to use the [Flex 4.5 skin class for your TextInputs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/skins/mobile/TextInputSkin.html):
>
> `<textInput skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin" />`